# almost surely convergence of a random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

I came across the following problem: Let $\xi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{P})$. Can we obtain  that $\xi/T^{\epsilon}$ converges almost-sure to zero, for any $\epsilon$ as $T$ tends to infinite?
Thus, is $\frac{\xi}{T^{\epsilon}}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow }0$ right?
Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: The assumption $\xi\in L^2$ is too much. It is enough that $\xi$ is finite almost surely. Then the limit is zero on the set where $\xi$ is finite.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks. $\xi$ is a random variable.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. If it is finite by according to your definition, then $\xi/T^\epsilon\to 0$ *for any* $\omega$, not only almost surely.

Answer (score -1):

$X=\lim_{T\to\infty}\xi/T^{\epsilon}$ exists and by the dominated convergence theorem $$0=\lim_{T\to\infty}E(\lvert\xi/T^{\epsilon}\rvert)=E(\lvert X\rvert)$$ so $X=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I can obtain convergence $L^{1}$ from your equation $0=\lim_{T\to\infty}E(\lvert\xi/T^{\epsilon}\rvert)=E(\lvert X\rvert)$. However, this convergence does not imply almost surely.

Comment: @weilinhy Well $X$ is defined to be the limit (possibly taking values in $\{+\infty,-\infty\}$) and $X$ has been shown to be $0$ almost surely.

Comment: @ user375366 Thanks for your help. Is $\frac{\xi}{T^{\epsilon}}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow }0$ is right?

Comment: @weilinhy Yes it converges to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: @ user375366  Thanks for your kindly help.